# Is there a Truecrypt reader application, written in Java or Flash?

Tags: truecrypt

Is there an application available for reading Truecrypt volumes, written in Java (.jar) or Flash? I'm in a restricted environment running Windows XP with Software policy enabled, and cannot run executables.

I've found [an application](http://www.trupax.com/home.html) for creating the volumes (written in Java), but now I need a reader.

Comment: if you're in a restricted environment, maybe there's a reason they want to control the software you're using.

Comment: @aking1012: Yes... to make administration easier. But Truecrypt requires administrative permissions as well, so just allowing the application is not option at the moment. My USB memory stick has encrypted containers in case I loose it (that happened to me before, but the data was unencrypted).

Comment: Well, it seems to be possible to read Truecrypt volumes according to [the docs](http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/?s=non-admin-users), but I still in need of an alternative (non-executable), preferably using Java.

Answer (score 0):

There is unlikely to be such an application.  The TrueCrypt docs say:

> TrueCrypt needs a device driver to provide transparent on-the-fly encryption/decryption

The filesystem that reads and writes the encrypted disk blocks is not part of TrueCrypt.  A TrueCrypt volume is basically a raw disk partition with sectors encrypted by the device driver.  Any application that claims to read the TC volume would have to implement the filesystem that was layered on the volume when the data was written (e.g., NTFS, FAT32, ext3, etc.).